# GitLab always Redirects to HTTPS

Tags: gitlab

I would like to run GitLab behind an Apache Reverse Proxy. The Apache makes all the SSL Stuff.

I´ve configured gitlab.rb like this.

```
external_url 'https://gitlab.example.com'
nginx['listen_address'] = '192.168.178.63'
nginx['listen_port'] = 8888
nginx['listen_https'] = false
nginx['external_users'] = ['http']
```

but when i enter the 192.168.178.63 in my webbrowser Gitlab always redirects me to https://192.168.178.63 but thats wrong the embedded Webserver from gitlab shoud do everithing with HTTP only

The problem is

```
external_url 'https://gitlab.example.com'
```

if i change it to

```
external_url 'http://gitlab.example.com'
```

everything works fine but it does not solve my  problem because now gitlab thinks the external URL is only a HTTP not HTTPS.

How can I kill this redirect to https? That the Gitlab embedded Webserver does everything with http and the reverse proxy the ssl stuff

Thanks.

Comment: how did you resolve this? Could you comment on the proposed answer and accept it, if it is valid?

Answer (score 2):

The **external_url** has to be set in GitLab only http, https will be enabled on your reverse proxy:

```
external_url 'http://gitlab.example.com'
```

Do not forget to reconfigire Gitlab after making changes.

```
gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

In your reverse proxy set:

```
proxy_pass http://192.168.178.63:8888
```

Comment: This advice goes against Gitlab's doc: https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#supporting-proxied-ssl which says that `external_url` must be set to a string beginning with `https://`.

Answer (score 1):

GitLab does support reverse proxies, even when you configure `external_url` with HTTPS.

> By default, Omnibus GitLab auto-detects whether to use SSL if `external_url` contains `https://` and configures NGINX for SSL termination. However, if configuring GitLab to run behind a reverse proxy or an external load balancer, some environments may want to terminate SSL outside the GitLab application. To do this, edit `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` to prevent the bundled NGINX from handling SSL termination:
>
> ```
> nginx['listen_port'] = 80
> nginx['listen_https'] = false
> ```

See [the docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#external-proxy-and-load-balancer-ssl-termination) for more details.